# iphone 5 won't recognize link to div ID

Tags: html, ios, iphone

I'm developing a site for a local chimney sweeper who has a ton of services to offer. For best UX, we decided to make a list of services at the top of the page with a link to the matching section by div ID i.e. if you click on the 'Relining' service, you would be taken to Relining by way of 'services#relining' in the href.

This works everywhere except for when we got to iOS testing - has anyone else come across this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using an anchor tag for the section you want to link to?

For example: `<a name="relining"></a>` at beginning of the Relining `<div>` and linking to it using `<a href="#relining">Relining</a>`

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/hopkins_matt/ne6b71hb/

Comment: Huh - that seemed to do the trick! Any reasons why that would take and not the id?

Comment: Not entirely sure, just know that the anchor tag seems to always work. I'm sure someone has a great explanation, but I just always fallback to this when I have issues.